# How to convert a folder of images from .pdf to .png?

Tags: bash, image, function, pdf, png

I have a folder of pdf files(~ 1600 images). I want to convert all .pdf images into .png images.
How can I do it?

**I tried**:

> find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec pdftoppm -r 300 -png {}
> {} ;

But have errors like:

```
Syntax Error: non-embedded font using identity encoding: Arial
Syntax Error: non-embedded font using identity encoding: Arial,Bold
Syntax Error: Can't get Fields array<0a>
Syntax Warning: Mismatch between font type and embedded font file
Syntax Error: Expected the optional content group list, but wasn't able to find it, or it isn't an Array
```

Is there any other solution for conversion?

Comment: what language is that? it doesn't look like python. Are you executing this in bash?

Comment: Yes you are right, it is bash.

Comment: You are making life difficult for yourself. Do one, correctly first. Then worry about the others. Also, you don't need `find` if they are all in the same directory - you know where they are already - no need to find anything.

Comment: I don't know `pdftoppm`, but two things are weird with your code: You are supplying to this tool the identical filename twice, and you don't escape the terminating semicolon. In any case, if you are using _GNU find_, you can use the option `-D exec`, which will show you exactly what is being executed. Note that this debugging option must come Immediately after `find`, before the starting directory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) to convert a png to a pdf

```bash
convert input.pdf -density 300 -alpha remove output.png
```

Here:

- the `-density 300` sets the DPI resolution to 300
- the `-alpha remove` makes it so the PDF file is not see through (an issue that can often, but not always happen)

You can use this to do something like this

```bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec convert {} -density 300 -alpha remove {}.png \;
```

Notice that the output filename will be `somefile.pdf.png` this way thou.

Comment: So, if i use the above command line starting with find, do i expect that the pdf files remains in the folder and the png i.e. converted files are added to that folder ?

Comment: This will create the pdf files in the same folder as it's run in, as long as the file name does not overlap, it should not overwrite any files (the `{}.png` part determines the output file as the input file with `.png` added to the end).

If you don't understand the above command, and you're scared of losing files, I would recommend creating a copy of the folder, and trying it in that copy instead so you don't lose anything.

Comment: No worries! please remember to mark this as the answer if it helped you, so it can also help others.

Comment: Sure, i will do that, it just takes some time to convert, as and when I finish i will mark if it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create PNG versions of all PDFs in the current directory with **ImageMagick** like this:

```
magick mogrify -density 300 -format PNG *.pdf
```

---

If you want the output files in a sub-directory called `OUTPUT`, use:

```
mkdir OUTPUT
magick mogrify -path OUTPUT -density 300 -format PNG *.pdf
```

---

As you have 1600 PDFs, you might consider using **GNU Parallel** to do them in parallel for you:

```
parallel magick {} -density 300 {.}.png ::: *.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

When running a folder of PDFs it is very common to get a range of warnings and errors during conversion. This is desirable, as it shows you exactly which files are sub standard, and need repair.

If you suppress `pdftoppm` errors by its own switch or by running through a different app such as GhostScript or its wrapper ImageMagick then you are not addressing the issues as to why those PDFs are faulty.

As an example this file command will report a font error.
`pdftoppm -png filename.pdf filename.png`

reports `Syntax Error: Couldn't find a font for '3of9Barcode', subst is 'ArialUnicode'`

No matter what other application we use the output image will always be corrupt. since in Acrobat Reader it should be like this !
[image]

[image]

So for each PDF that fails, you need to analyse more closely and then substitute the correct fix.

Arguably GhostScript is very often used to attempt "font repair" by substitution, but the substitution needs to be very specific per file, using knowledge of WHY! a substituted font may be better or worse.

Here GhostScript (thus ImageMagick) will apparently produce an acceptable visual.

[image]

HOWEVER at the cost of considerably more errors that warn of worse problems.

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=png16m -r256 -sOutputFile=filename.png filename.pdf
GPL Ghostscript 10.01.1 (2023-03-27)
Copyright (C) 2023 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
Loading font Arial (or substitute) from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Regular
Loading font Arial,Bold (or substitute) from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Arial (or substitute) from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Regular
Loading font Arial,Bold (or substitute) from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Arial (or substitute) from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Regular
Loading font Arial (or substitute) from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Regular
Loading font Arial,Bold (or substitute) from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading font Arial,Bold (or substitute) from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold
Loading CIDFont 3of9Barcode substitute from %rom%Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf
Loading font CourierNew (or substitute) from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusMonoPS-Regular
Loading CIDFont Arial substitute from %rom%Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf

The following warnings were encountered at least once while processing this file:
        encountered more q than Q

   **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
   **** The file was produced by:
   **** >>>> ?? <<<<
   **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
   **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
   **** specification.
```

You can batch all those files with similar worded error, if there are many, and run GhostScript or a `pdftoppm font configuration` specific to the group of failures.

Answer (score -1):

You probably use gs command tool on MacOS

1. Install ghostscript

brew install ghostscript

2. Execute one line on your shell

```
find . -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec bash -c 'FILE="$1"; gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=png16m -r256  -sOutputFile="${FILE%.pdf}_page%03d.png" "${FILE}";' _ '{}' \;
```

Thanks.